# Ubuntu, detect new display

Tags: ubuntu, display, multi-monitor, gdm

Running Ubuntu based Os on my Laptop, I have an external HDMI display that is not detected. I tried `lspci` and `xrandr` but the display stay "disconnected".

How can I detect the display and extend my desktop ?

Thanks

---

**lspci -d ::0300 -nnk**

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation UHD Graphics 620 [8086:5917] (rev 07)
        DeviceName: Onboard IGD
        Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company UHD Graphics 620 [103c:83b2]

        Kernel driver in use: i915
        Kernel modules: i915
```

**lspci -d ::0302 -nnk**

No result

**sudo dmidecode -s system-product-name**

```
HP EliteBook 850 G5
```

Comment: Your laptop may have more than one GPU, and the HDMI connector and the internal display may be hardwired to different GPUs. First, please run `lspci -d ::0300 -nnk` and edit the output into your question. That should tell us which GPU you're currently using, and perhaps if there is another GPU present. Then, please run `sudo mount -t debugfs none /sys/kernel/debug` to mount a DebugFS virtual filesystem, and then run `sudo cat /sys/kernel/debug/vgaswitcheroo/switch`: the result should reveal if your system has a way to switch outputs between GPUs. This information will help us help you.

Comment: Mounting the debug fs does not work: `mount: /sys/kernel/debug: none already mounted on /sys/fs/bpf.` and `/sys/fs/bpf` is empty. Thanks for your help

Comment: Try using any other word in place of `none`: when mounting a virtual filesystem like `debugfs`, the device name is not needed and is just a placeholder to satisfy the mount command. Please add information on the exact model of your laptop (the output of `sudo dmidecode -s system-product-name` would probably be best). Also, the other GPU might use a different PCI class code: you might want to try `lspci -d ::0302 -nnk` also.

Comment: I tried to mount with other names but still the same result : `mount: /sys/kernel/debug: 4578478 already mounted or mount point busy.`

Comment: I guess I managed to mount it : `mount | grep -i debugfs` : `debugfs on /sys/kernel/debug type debugfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)` but there are no "vgaswitcheroo" directory in that folder.

Comment: Or perhaps it was already mounted by default, which I did not expect... anyway, there are 6 different generations of HP Elitebook 850, and there should be a number after the `G` at the end of the model name.

Comment: It's a **G5**, sorry it was not pasted.

Comment: Solution which works for me: 1. suspend computer 2. connect display 3. wake up computer (ubuntu 21.04, wayland, gnome, kernel 5.11)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, so you have an HP Elitebook 850 G5, which does not seem to have the optional discrete Radeon R59 GPU installed, and so it's working with just the Intel GPU that's integrated into the processor. So it should be pretty straightforward, with none of the complications of multiple GPUs.

If the HDMI port is listed as "disconnected" in the `xrandr` output, (e.g. as `HDMI-1`), then please verify:

- the cable is good (i.e. it works with some other computer/display)
- the display is powered on and (if applicable) has the correct HDMI input selected
- the cable is firmly plugged in at both ends

If `xrandr` still shows the HDMI display as `disconnected`, then there might be a hardware problem.

But if it shows the HDMI as `connected` but disabled, it's waiting for activation. In that case, you would need to do something like `xrandr --output HDMI-1 --auto` (or the equivalent action in the GUI configuration panel of your desktop environment) to enable it. If working on the command line, you might want to add an option like `--left-of eDP-1` to specify the location of the new display relative to the laptop's built-in display, or `--same-as eDP-1` if you want the same view on both displays.

Comment: Thanks a LOT for your support. All ports (except the default "eDP-1") are disconnected. I am working elsewhere today, without external monitors. I will not be able to do it in the GUI because the monitor is not shown, but will try the command as soon as possible and keep you informed.

Comment: The issue seems to be with my screen. However some are working and some don't. I got one, smaller than the original one, but who is detected automatically.